# Converting array of bool to array of int

Tags: c++

I have following struct:

```
 struct nodo {
 array<array<bool,19>,19> tablero; 
 array<int,2> p1,p2;     
 int d1,d2;                             
 int u1,u2;                             
 } mys;
```

which is passed by argument to a function

```
void myf(nodo mys){
// that attempts to do the following conversion:
array<array<int,19>,19> lab=mys.tablero;
}
```

And I am receiving the following error:

> error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘lab = mys.nodo::tablero’

So I assume the conversion cannot be done like that. What is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Two `for` loops would do the trick.

Comment: What do you need to do with that `bool` array? Also why do you need it to be an `int` array in the first place?

Comment: @Mark Ransom Is that the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Uh, not a duplicate, `array` has no such constructor.

Comment: Does efficiency really matter in this case? There's nothing straight-forward which will be any faster anyway.

Comment: The struct uses an array of bool because the memory is important. Then I have to use one of these for some other stuff, and I need the most efficient way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, so the most straightforward method is simply:

```
  for (i=0; i<=18; i++){
        for (j=0; j<=18 ; j++){
                lab[i][j]= mys.tablero[i][j];
            }
 }
```

As  Mark Ransom suggested in the first place

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can assign a 2D boolean array to a 2D integer array (of size 19x19 as in your case):

```
for(int i=0; i<19; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<19; j++) {
       lab[i][j] = (tablero[i][j])?1:0;
    }
}
```

Please note the use of ternary operator in the assignment statement. If the

```
tablero[i][j]
```

is true then

```
lab[i][j] will be 1, otherwise it will be 0.
```

Of course you may assign different integer values as well.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

These two arrays

```
array<array<bool,19>,19> tablero
```

and

```
array<array<int,19>,19> lab;
```

have different types and there is no implicit conversion from one array to another.

You can either write loops yourself or use some standard algorithms as it is shown in this demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main() 
{

    std::array<std::array<bool,19>,19> tablero; 
    std::array<std::array<int,19>,19> tablero1;

    std::accumulate( tablero.begin(), tablero.end(), tablero1.begin(),
                     []( auto it, const auto &a ) 
                     { 
                        return std::copy( a.begin(), a.end(), it->begin() ), ++it;
                     } );

    return 0;
}
```

Your compiler has to support specifier auto in lambda expressions that the code would compile.

Or the same program but with some output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 3;
    std::array<std::array<bool, N>, N> tablero = 
    {
        {
            { true, false, false },
            { false, true, false },
            { false, false, true }
        }
    }; 
    std::array<std::array<int, N>, N> tablero1;

    std::accumulate( tablero.begin(), tablero.end(), tablero1.begin(),
                     []( auto it, const auto &a ) 
                     { 
                        return std::copy( a.begin(), a.end(),it->begin() ), ++it;
                     } );

    for ( const auto &a : tablero )
    {
        for ( auto b : a ) std::cout << std::boolalpha << b << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( const auto &a : tablero1 )
    {
        for ( auto x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


true false false 
false true false 
false false true 

1 0 0 
0 1 0 
0 0 1
```